# Why is socket.on() from a previous screen component executed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, socket.io

I have two react components. the first `Lobby` uses react-native-navigation to push `Gameroom` to the stack. It passes props such as the socket object and other data to the Gameroom component

when the back button of the navigation bar is pressed inside Gameroom, a socket.io `leave` event is emitted, and I have verified it is heard by the server, so the socket passed through props works. the server then emits an event `left` back to the socket.io room (Gameroom component).

the `left` event listener, if placed inside Gameroom's `componentDidMount()` does not execute. However, if the same socket.io event listener is placed in `Lobby` component (previous screen) `componentDidMount()` the event is heard

I've tried adding the event listener to multiple componentDidMount functions, I also thought about using the Context API, but I'm not working with nested components. I'm passing the socket object in react-native-navigation's `{passProps}` from screen to screen

```
Lobby:

imports ...
const socket = io("http://192.xxx.xxx.xx:3000");
export default class Lobby extends React.Component {
  static options(passProps) {
    return {
      topBar: {
        background: {
          color: "transparent"
        },
        drawBehind: true,
        visible: true,
        animate: true,
        leftButtons: [
          {
            id: "leave",
            icon: require("../assets/img/Chevron.png")
          }
        ]
      }
    };
  }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: "Initializing...",
      queue: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    Navigation.events().bindComponent(this);
    socket.emit("lobbyEntry");
    socket.on("lobbyEntry", entry => {
      this.setState({ queue: entry.lobby, username: socket.id });
    });
    socket.on("userJoined", lobby => {
      this.setState({ queue: lobby });
    });
    // socket.on("left", () => {
    //   alert("Opponent Left...Oh well");
    //   Navigation.pop(this.props.componentId);
    // });
  }
  navigationButtonPressed({ buttonId }) {
    switch (buttonId) {
      case "leave":
        socket.emit("leave");
        Navigation.popToRoot(this.props.componentId);
        break;
    }
  }
  createMatch = () => {
    if (this.state.username != "Initializing...") {
      socket.emit("findMatch");
      socket.on("alreadyCreated", () => {
        alert("You already created a match!");
      });
      socket.on("listUsers", lobby => {
        this.setState({ queue: lobby });
      });
      socket.on("matchFound", data => {
        Navigation.push(this.props.componentId, {
          component: {
            name: "Gameroom",
            passProps: {
              room: data.id,
              socket: socket,
              firstMove: data.firstMove,
              p1: data.p1,
              p2: data.p2
            }
          }
        });
      });
    } else {
      alert("Wait for Username to be initialized...");
    }
  };
  render() {
    const bg = getBackground();
    return (
      <ImageBackground source={bg} style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}>
        <View style={styles.title_container}>
          <Text style={styles.title_sm}>Matchmaking Lobby</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.alt_text_container}>
          <Text style={styles.alt_text_md}>Username:</Text>
          <Text style={styles.alt_text_md}>{this.state.username}</Text>
        </View>
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: "column",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center"
          }}
        >
          <XplatformButton onPress={this.createMatch} text={"Create a Match"} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.alt_text_container}>
          <Text style={styles.alt_text_sm}>Players actively searching...</Text>
          <FlatList
            style={styles.alt_text_container}
            data={this.state.queue}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
              <Text style={styles.alt_text_md} key={index}>
                {item}
              </Text>
            )}
          />
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}
```

Gameroom:

```
import ...
export default class Gameroom extends React.Component {
  static options(passProps) {
    return {
      topBar: {
        title: {
          fontFamily: "BungeeInline-Regular",
          fontSize: styles.$navbarFont,
          text: "Gameroom - " + passProps.room,
          color: "#333"
        },
        background: {
          color: "transparent"
        },
        drawBehind: true,
        visible: true,
        animate: true,
        leftButtons: [
          {
            id: "leave",
            icon: require("../assets/img/Chevron.png")
          }
        ]
      }
    };
  }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    Navigation.events().bindComponent(this);
  }

  navigationButtonPressed({ buttonId }) {
    switch (buttonId) {
      case "leave":
        this.props.socket.emit("leave");
        Navigation.pop(this.props.componentId);
        break;
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // socket.on("left", () => {
    //   alert("Opponent Left...Oh well");
    //   Navigation.pop(this.props.componentId);
    // });
  }

  render() {
    const bg = getBackground();
    return this.props.p2 != null ? (
      <Gameboard
        room={this.props.room}
        you={
          this.props.socket.id == this.props.p1.username
            ? this.props.p1.marker
            : this.props.p2.marker
        }
        opponent={
          this.props.socket.id != this.props.p1.username
            ? this.props.p2.marker
            : this.props.p1.marker
        }
        move={this.props.firstMove}
        socket={this.props.socket}
      />
    ) : (
      <ImageBackground style={styles.container} source={bg}>
        <View style={{ marginTop: 75 }}>
          <Text style={styles.alt_text_md}>
            Waiting for Opponent to Join...
          </Text>
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}
```

I expect the event listener to execute from the current screen's componentDidMount() function, but it only executes if it's inside the previous screen's componentDidMount()

Answer (score 2):

When you create a `component`,

> the `constructor` -> `componentWillMount` -> `render` -> `componentDidMount` is
>   followed.

In your `Lobby` class, the event listener is run because it is in `ComponentDidmont`.

However, the event listener of the `Gameroom` class is inside the `constructor`. If executed within the `constructor`, the event cannot be heard because it is not yet `rendered`.

Event listeners are called when they appear on the screen

**Usage**

```js
  componentDidMount() {
    this.navigationEventListener = Navigation.events().bindComponent(this);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // Not mandatory
    if (this.navigationEventListener) {
      this.navigationEventListener.remove();
    }
  }
```

Comment: This answer contains useful information regarding the call order, but this did not change anything. to be clear: its not  `react-native-navigation` event listener that isn't being called. it's socket.io's `this.props.socket.on("left")` event that's isn't being executed.
I made the changes suggested and the result is the same.

Comment: @Jim Can you see the price of 'passProps.room'?

Comment: the price? I can see the data. passProps room is accessible, as well as this.props.socket.id

Comment: Did you try `passProps.socket` ??

Comment: I will, but im curious, why would that have any different effect given that I can access the socket object with this.props.socket?

Comment: The object of the socket you delivered did not convey the function, but the data that the object had.

Comment: this isn't making sense. the socket is passed to the next component (`Gameroom`) just fine, because I use `this.props.socket.emit("leave")` from inside that component, which works. I can also `alert(this.props.socket.id)` effectively. Using `passProps` in componentDidMount() won't work anyway, passProps isn't accessible?

Comment: Could you try this? `this.state={ sokect: this.props.navigation.state.params.component.passProps.socket }`

Comment: that suggestion results in `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.state')`. because im inside the constructor, I modified it to `props.navigation.state` which is also resulting in the same error.

Comment: Did you run it in the constructor?

Comment: `constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      socket: props.navigation.state.params.component.passProps.socket
    };
  }`

Comment: this is not using react navigation. react-native-navigation by wix is used

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197905/discussion-between-jim-and-hong-develop).